# How does the class constructor parameter property in typescript work?

Tags: angular, typescript, class

Question: *"How, if ...*

**Given**

1. an angular Service class:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FooService {

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

  ...
}
```

2. an Angular component class:

```
@Component({
 ...
})
export class AuthorManagementComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor( public databaseService: DatabaseService ) { }

  ...
}
```

**Where**: `HttpClient` actually is a declared class:

```
export declare class HttpClient {
    private handler;
    constructor(handler: HttpHandler);
...
}
```

*... get's the HttpClient initialized without a HttpHandler when the declared constructor requires it?"*

Because i can not do: `const httpClient = new HttpClient();`.

**Further Information:** I am using Angular in Version 10 and its `HttpClient`. It might have something to do with how Angular itself interprets it during compile time?

I am very curious to understand whats going on behind the scene.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
As @LiHao and @Phix correctly pointed out, the reason is how angulars dependency injection works. Although, i do not get the point where angular get's the `HttpHandler` for the `HttpClient` and, why, if to be injected in that way the implementation of the `HttpClient` itself has no `@Injectable` though, by reading the docs, it is necessary for the DI.

Comment: I thought your question is not about typescript, Angular dependence injection done this part. By the way, `HttpClient` constructor need `HttpHandler` so in Angular just use `constructor injection` Angular will done this part.

Comment: Well, Angular is using typescript and the parameter property in constructors is a typescript feature (or am i wrong?).
Okay, if Angular is doing this part behind the scene, can you clarify how?

Comment: Check the docs about [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

Comment: Thank you, having a look sice @LiHao indirectly pointed it by mentioning ```constructor injection```.